# What is the priority order mechanism of dns client configuration in windows?

Tags: windows, dns, network-adapter, netsh, query

I wonder what is the order of dns query in windows?

for example, suppose I have two dns server configured with different **DNS Index**.

to quote what is [DNS Index](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731521(v=ws.10))

> A lower number for the DNSIndex parameter corresponds to a higher preference. If no index is specified, then the server is added with the lowest preference.

back to our example:

```
Server A      10.0.0.1      ( index 20 )
Server B      10.0.0.2      ( index 10 )
```

we can see that **`B`** has a higher priority.

say I have `x.com` to resolve, but this record only exist on server A.

---

Question is:

when will it use `A`(server with a high index, low priority)?

1. `x.com` can not be resolved by `B`
2. when `B` is down

Comment: See answers here: https://serverfault.com/questions/355414/how-is-dns-lookup-order-determined